# HTML Formatting Aligning Buttons in a Box

Tags: html, css

I've been brushing up on html, css and javascript by working on a little project that I thought would be useful. It is a recipe finder based on what recipes I have in home. Anyways, my question is about lining up a few of the elements in the html page.
The part of the html page in question is:

```
<form>
<select size=10 id="first"></select>
<button type="button" id="addAll" onclick="rightAll()">
    Add All
</button>
<button type="button" id="removeAll" onclick="leftAll()">
    Remove All
</button>
<button type="button" id="add" onclick="right()">
    >>
</button>
<button type="button" id="remove" onclick="left()">
    &lt;&lt;
</button>
<select size=10 id="second"></select>
</form>
```

My css document:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
select{
    width: 300px;
}
```

Because all the elements are in a form tag they all appear inline. I tried putting the buttons in a table, but the tables formatting put the first select on one line, the table on a new line, and the second select on a new line.
Here is what my formatting looks like now:[image]
and here is what I want it to look like (thanks to paint)[image]
I'm sure I could figure out how to center the buttons vertically in the form, but if you could help me out with that too then I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Try changing the HTML. Add wrapping divs and other layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<form>
    <div id="sel1">
        <select size=10 id="first"></select>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <div id="buttons1">
             <button type="button" id="addAll" onclick="rightAll()">
             Add All
             </button>
             <button type="button" id="removeAll" onclick="leftAll()">
             Remove All
             </button>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons2">
             <button type="button" id="add" onclick="right()">
             >>
             </button>
             <button type="button" id="remove" onclick="left()">
             &lt;&lt;
             </button>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="sel2">
         <select size=10 id="second"></select>
     </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
select{
    width: 300px;
}
div {
  float: left;
}  
#buttons1, #buttons2 {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

It is up to you to tweak paddings and margins to leave it at your desire.

Comment: This helped so much. Thank you. I have been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

you should use div if you want to extent your design further, table is not responsive directly and type of fixed layout with messy code , you may try use div and other css property .

anyway just for that middle section , you may try div inside your table td like this :

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">
<button type="button" id="addAll" onclick="rightAll()">
    Add All
</button>
<div>
<div style="width:50%;float:right;">
<button type="button" id="removeAll" onclick="leftAll()">
    Remove All
</button>
<div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">
<button type="button" id="add" onclick="right()">
    >>
</button>
<div>
<div style="width:50%;float:right;">
<button type="button" id="remove" onclick="left()">
    &lt;&lt;
</button>
<div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Cheers !